# Source .bashrc file in bash globally

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python

So I am trying to write a script which compiles VMAF from the GIT and I need to change the PYTHONPATH location to the installation directory. The script is working good, and it is installing VMAF, but the problem is that when I source the changes in .bashrc it is valid until the bash script completes, and I want to make them globally. I understand that the bash process is isolating the changes but is there a way to execute the source that it persists the execution of the script? This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir $HOME/install
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python-tk -y
sudo pip install --upgrade scikit-learn h5py numpy scipy matplotlib pandas

cd $HOME/install
git clone https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf.git
cd $HOME/install/vmaf
make
echo "export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/install/vmaf/python:\$PYTHONPATH" | sudo tee -a $HOME/.bashrc
echo "alias ll='ls -al --color'" | sudo tee -a $HOME/.bashrc

source $HOME/.bashrc
./unittest
```

Comment: To add global exports, add a new file to `/etc/profile.d/` add global aliases to `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` depending on your distro (see `/etc/profile` around line  18 `# Source global bash config` (works only for interactive shells)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could define the global variables in /etc/bash.bashrc and run unittest with `bash -c unittest`. I *think* that will work, but YMMV.

I can't help but point out that there is free open-source software like Chef and Puppet designed to automate stuff like this. While there's a learning curve to overcome, both are well-documented with tutorials. I'm partial to Chef and would use it if I had to do what you're attempting to do here.

Take a look at https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/ubuntu/free/configure-a-resource/ to get a feel for how to use Chef in local mode, which is what I'd do in this situation. Here's a Chef script I wrote to get you started,  but use it at your own risk. I haven't tested it. Save it to something like install_vmaf.rb.

```
include_recipe 'python'
include_recipe 'python::pip'

['python-dev','python-pip','python-tk'].each do |p|
  package p do
    action :install
  end
end

['scikit-learn','h5py','numpy','scipy','matplotlib','pandas'].each do |p|
  python_pip p do
    action :install
  end
end

git "/path/to/check/out/to" do
  repository "https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
end
```

This is incomplete, so you'll need to add a resource block to handle the build process. It's several years old, but take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/298013/installing-something-from-source-using-chef-should-i-be-doing-some-checks for some direction on how to do this.

Lastly, keep in mind `chef-client` is meant to be run as root, so you'll want to use the "user" property within the "git" resource block to set ownership of the cloned vmaf repo correctly. See https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html for more info.